# Need a regex that validates a string with varying size

Tags: regex

I need regex that validates a string that:

- has 4 or 5 letters
- then one underscore
- then either an I or O (only one of them)
- then one underscore
- then 4 numeric digits

Now here where it complicates further.
After all that it may have:

- another underscore
- then 4 numeric digits.

In the end all these must be valid:

ASDF_I_0002

ASDFG_O_0003_0324

ASDF_O_0001

ASDF_I_0001_0001

Thank you.

Comment: Is this homework? If so it should be tagged as such.

Comment: I am simply crap at regex. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- has 4 or 5 letters (A-Z)

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}
  ```
- then one underscore

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}_
  ```
- then either an I or O (only one of them)

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}_[IO]
  ```
- then one underscore

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}_[IO]_
  ```
- then 4 numeric digits

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}_[IO]_[0-9]{4}
  ```

After all that it *may have*:

```
    [A-Z]{4,5}_[IO]_[0-9]{4}()?
```

- another underscore

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}_[IO]_[0-9]{4}(_)?
  ```
- then 4 numeric digits.

  ```
  [A-Z]{4,5}_[IO]_[0-9]{4}(_[0-9]{4})?
  ```

You've lined out your requirements so nicely, I wonder where the problem was to make a regex from them. ;)

Comment: Thanks. All great. just [A-Z] instead of [a-z].

Answer (score 1):

has 4 or 5 letters

- \w{4-5}

then one underscore

- _

then either an I or O (only one of them)

- [IO]

then one underscore

- _

then 4 numeric digits

- \d{4}

Put it all together

```
\w{4-5}_[IO]_\d{4}
```

Although to match all your test cases you need to extend this

```
\w{4-5}_[IO](_\d{4}){1,2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
^\w{4,5}_(I|O)_\d{4}(_\d{4})?$
```

**EDIT**: Compared to other solutions it evaluates ;-)

```
^\w{4,5}_[IO](_\d{4}){1,2}$
```

Comment: Nice catch in the second expression. +1